# Is there a way to develop real NATIVE mobile cross platform apps without wrapping things?

Tags: mobile, compiler-construction, cross-platform

I try to find a way to develop real native mobile apps, cross-platform. The amount of tools I found is huge, very huge.

All of the tools I have tried 'said' that the end result will be native, but in fact it isn't true. It is an executable with a webbrowser in it and some extra native layer/framwork to device specific features.

The reason I want a real native app is:

- Speed and compact
- Avoid browser issues
- Market acceptance
- Avoid easy/'script kiddie" reverse engineering

The products I have tried:

- Appcelerator (does not work correctly on my system)
- PhoneGap (does not create REAL native apps)
- Embarcadero radPHP EX2 (uses PhoneGap)
- Embarcadero radStudio EX2 (cannot create mobile/android apps?)
- Adobe Flash Builder (Works very well but relies on Air, so apps are huge and no
  native devices such as vibration (posible, but must write it
  yourself)
- Flash Develop (but same as Adobe Flash Builder)
- ..... and some others ;-) like moSync......

Currently I have downloaded "RhoStudio" but has some doubts about it because in the introduction video they talk about the things that I don't want.

Target directions are in the first place Android, iOS and maybe in the future Windows Phone. 
Note: I don't have a Mac so I cannot compile it on a Mac.

Is what I want impossible or is there such product around that can do this?

**EDIT: 
See my answer, the answer is NO!**

Comment: Tried RhoStudio but is to complicated and do the same like all. What do people think about AppMobi? Is it good?

Comment: Have you heard of Applause? (http://www.applause-framework.com)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tried it by download it, download eclipse, install latest JDK, start eclipse and want to import the projects and get error: Resource '/itemsisApp' already exists. Is it worth it to try to fix that (or am i able to fix that)?

Comment: What about Icenium and/or Xamarin's stuff? For the latter: you can write large, non-UI chunks in a C# library then specialize the UI code.

Comment: Two and a half years later, I hope you've discovered Embarcadero XE7 or Xamarin forms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After 2 years asking this question I can say: NO, it is NOT possible, it's a myth.

All products I have tried use some kind of wrapping or use a second language as a layer to the call the native stuff. Although the libraries are native, the main program is not. The latest answer of Cosku with smartface.io is a good example, they claim it is native but it is NOT.

Why is it so difficult? The problem is the programming language (differences in language that makes it complex) that is required for a platform. It is too complex to translate a second language into the platform's main language and it's specific libraries, you can only achieve this by wrapping things with native binaries. Second obstacle is the needed compiler that must be able to run cross-platform.

But why rely on a second language or third-party development tool to build apps when the output is mostly the same is bad, the problem is perfectly illustrated in this image:
http://xkcd.com/927/

[image]

The image is about standards, but that's what happen, creating a new standard for a standard. For example, when using PhoneGap, you have to learn the basics of the PhoneGap API. You rely on a 'new standard' calling PhoneGap. The problem with this is that you completely rely on PhoneGap support and it existence. It can introduce a second weakness in the lifecycle of an app.

IMO, if you want to wrap things to make it cross-platform it is not a smart idea to rely on third-party products and libraries. Better is to write a wrapper yourself, like I did and skip the bloat. A real benefit of this all is that you wrote the wrapper code yourself and you understand underlying structures. Besides it is easier to extend or change and you can skip the things you don't need.

Today I create and design the UI of an app in the longest existing and stable 'language' HTML with a javascript interface. The app can also run in a browser too and does not break when there is a specific function missing, like vibrate for example. You can not get the same results with phonegap, try it! You can design the app with responsive techniques at ease like a normal website (try this in Android for example ;-)). Technically, it can run everywhere, on any platform in a browser or webview but don't use any special Mobile javascript libraries! You don't need these special libraries, really, use the 'normal' library versions instead.

I have wrote a compiler/obfuscator for it to 'pack' the UI-source into just one file that will be loaded by the native shell. This is to protect the source, so it is not easy to view or modify the source.

The only thing I have to do, to support the app platform is write a native wrapper for it. If a platform dies for some reason (for example Windows Mobile in the past), I only have to write a new wrapper for it. This is easier to do than write the whole program again from scratch. Besides, when there is a new platform it can also run in the platforms browser too.

If your app not rely on specific hardware (like a game) or can run without special hardware requirements, this is the way to go to extend the life-cycle of your app. Use HTML5 and javascript to design the GUI and use a native shell to use specific OS features.

Is it slow? I have to say no. At least don't use any bulky and bloated special designed mobile javascript library stuff and don't use the click event on touchscreen devices, use touchstart instead. Also the HTML engines will/are improved these days and there is better support for HTML5 features that enables you to write powerful HTML5 webapps without the need to implement this in a native language.

IMO, this the way to go (for me) and my journey to find the best way develop mobile apps cross-platform and to extend the life-cycle. Hopefully, it can help you too to decide what is the best to do.

Answer (score 5):

For cross-platform native iOS, Android, Mac, and Windows apps, check out [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com).  Code in C#, compile to native.  For iOS, you can leverage the XCode tools for app layout, and Xamarin Studio integrates very cleanly with it.

And for the sake of completeness, PhoneGap has a worthy (yes, WebView based) competitor in [TRIGGER.IO](http://trigger.io).  While it's approach is similar to PhoneGap/Cordova, it improves the API for accessing native functionality, simplifies push notifications, and performs much faster cloud builds.

I am not associated with either of these products in any way... I just like them both.

Comment: Hai Noah, thanks for your answer. It is not that I don't want to pay for something and trigger.io seems to be good but very pricy. Also not clear to me if you can run it on a windows system. Same as Xamarin. At first point of view I think I like trigger.io more than Xamarin.

Comment: @Erwinus, You can use it on both Windows and Mac. It can be pricy but I believe you can create and setup your project on a trial ( just cant publish to app stores ) I have been using trigger for over a year ( Switched from phonegap to trigger.io ) and have found that the productivity has gone way up, the way you can add components and modules is really nice, no fiddling with config files etc. On top of that you can build and deploy to your IOS devices from forge so no testflight that can helps out a lot in testing when using windows

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [www.codenameone.com](http://www.codenameone.com/)? It's open source, java based, only need eclipse or netbeans to develop.

Comment: I'm rooting for it. I think there are issues though on android. The last default android app I made with it ended up being even slower than a HTML5 app...even though it was native....if that's even possible. But My guess is they are working on this.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly

```
Appcelerator (does not work correctly on my system)
```

Is there a certain issue your facing ? are getting java errors or something, might not have been setup correctly.

Short answer is no, you have to have some level of abstraction in order to achieve this, java and objective-c are completely different languages, as well as Android and IOS SDK's having different methods, procedures, styles, design's etc. There is no way to have something work on both without there being a middle layer to convert or render.

Appcelerator will be the closet thing to what your looking for as its not a webview wrapper like the others, true it does interpret javascript, but because its not wrapped in a webview you avoid the browser issues.

Speed and compact comes more down how you code the app more than what its coded on, true Titanium apps will be bigger in size because of the library but that doesn't make it bad as such, the benefits of getting 2 apps far out weighs the extra few megabytes I would think.

I'm pretty sure all of these tools have market acceptance as they wouldn't be successful without it, again for the likes of apples requirements its down to the way you design it, not the tool in the background.

If you want to use IOS you will need a mac, if you want to publish in the app store alone you need xcode and the built project to use the application loader, I'm not aware of any tool (even the webview wrappers) that don't require you to have the IOS SDK as it can't run in the simulator, package the app or run any of the code without it.

If you want to make apps you have 2 choices, learn each platform or use one of these tools, if there was some magic tool that did everything I guarantee it would be the most popular thing on the planet and you would have heard about it / found it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info. With Appcelerator, i can't remember what exactly the problem was. It it sad to hear that I need a mac to develop for iOS. Expensive developer program, expensive hardware, cannot try before you buy. I think I will go (in the first place) for Android and maybe after that for Apple. Also i downloaded AppMobi XDK, seems to be promising, apple apps can be compiled in the cloud, what do you think about AppMobi? Is worth it?

Comment: thats just the way apple do it, you could try create a vm of mac osx but i've heard mixed things about the quality of this. Only just looked at it there, seems to be yet another HTML web view wrapper which I'm not mad about. In fairness never tried it nor heard of it before now, could be better than i think it is

Comment: Thanks again. Interface of AppMobi is good-lookin' but the first error is there (get some popups that it want to copy something to a location that doesn't exists). I think development is not finished yet and for some services you must pay. Not that I don't want to pay for something good but is on a monthly basis. I think i will go for android only at the first place and for some I use Flash Builder to develop (i can reuse some AS3 code from the past too).

Comment: +1 for even mentioning the word "design" and implying that good design can reduce the coding effort of porting the app

Answer (score 0):

This is one reason why "the cloud" is so popular. Instead of writing your app several times over, you write all of the functionality on a server. The actual "apps" are then simply your user interface to the functionality, which can be really simple depending on your needs. If it is that simple, then you could write the apps separately for each platform, but they would all use the same "cloud" backend.

If I am not mistaken, this is representative of what most apps by companies who have a cloud architecture do, and is also why many require a data connection.

I don't think that it is possible to write once and run everywhere without some kind of wrapper or layer, this is due to the fact that each platform has separate APIs and even programming languages. You would be hard pressed to write one set of source code that runs natively on both Apple and Android devices, for example. This is not to say that it isn't technically possible, desktop operating systems have had such cross-compiling portability for years with C/C++, and Java only made that much easier. Of course, the engineers of Mobile operating systems don't seem to share a vision of interoperable APIs.

To conclude, I would recommend A) writing the app twice (awful I know, but it will provide the reliablity of native execution on both devices, and can be done with minimal pain) or B) breaking down and using one of the "script-kiddie" frameworks. These actually may not be that bad if your app is simple enough, and it may not be that reverse-engineerable at all. If anyone has any suggestions as to the best "near-native" cross platform framework, that would be useful.

Comment: Ha, thanks for the info. Reverse engineering is simply to when it is an Android app and when it is not binary code. The apktool can do such things for you. For my first app i have used Adobe Flash Builder and is much more complicated to reverse engineer. So I use this one first. For my second app, still don't know what to do, i think i go for Android only because I don't have a mac. Do you know AppMobi, you can compile iOS in the cloud. Is it good?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several things to consider, if you want native look and feel there are frameworks like Sencha(www.sencha.com) and Kendo UI(http://www.kendoui.com/) that simulate it on JavaScript side. I found them both good looking on Android and iPhone but no support for Windows Phone yet.

If you are looking for real native widgets combined with HTML you can look into MoSync's Native UI(http://www.mosync.com/documentation/manualpages/jsnativeui-library), which support windows phone Metro UI too, or Titanium(http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html).

Anyway one other thing is that you can use packagers like Phonegap or MoSync or AppMobi(which I think uses something similar to PhoneGap build) to wrap your app and put it on App markets. from these list PhoneGap especially is not designed to provide you with any specific UI functionality although I have seen some attempts to add tab bar plugins to Phonegap.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but is NOT an answer to the question. Most of the things rely on PhoneGap and PhoneGap is not native.